# Data Table: Create new column in .SD while keeping old columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have successfully created a new column using R's data.table functionality. However, my usage of .SD[] in the logic seems to have removed my ability to use the ':=' symbol to add new columns, meaning I now have to explicitly list out of every column in my output.

You can take a look at my code below:

```
test <- data[, {
presentnugget = nuggetid
.SD[, .(futurebuddy = shift(sessionid[nuggetid == presentnugget], type = "lead"))]}, by = c("userid")]
```

The logic, in summary, groups the data by 'userid', and then for every row in the grouping, looks forward for a row with the same 'nuggetid' as the present row. It then takes the 'sessionid' of the matching row and appends it to the present row under the column 'futurebuddy'.

Output for a single group:

```
                                userid              futurebuddy
  2d44d548-7de0-4dc9-b874-ad62d72b688d 5c16ba6de6abe300010ec6d7
  2d44d548-7de0-4dc9-b874-ad62d72b688d 5c16bb633bee360001a809aa
  2d44d548-7de0-4dc9-b874-ad62d72b688d 5c4f4803ffe02000017d1104
  2d44d548-7de0-4dc9-b874-ad62d72b688d 5c4f5461ffe02000017d5853
  2d44d548-7de0-4dc9-b874-ad62d72b688d 5c07c9bab2dab300010f14c0
```

My problem is that all prior columns that existed in the 'data' object are now gone. When I try using the ':=' operator:

```
data[, {
presentnugget = nuggetid
.SD[, futurebuddy := shift(sessionid[nuggetid == presentnugget], type = "lead")]}, by = c("userid")]
```

It tells me:

```
.SD is locked. Using := in .SD's j is reserved for possible future use; a tortuously flexible way to modify by group. Use := in j directly to modify by group by reference.
```

Is there any way I can add a column within .SD[]? Or perhaps tell the operation to keep all existing columns? Thanks!

Comment: `data[, futurebuddy := {
presentnugget = nuggetid;
.SD[, .(futurebuddy = shift(sessionid[nuggetid == presentnugget],...`? You cannot change `.SD`, but you shouldn't need to.

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you. I was under the impression that when using { } after the second comma, all your logic had to be contained inside

Comment: The RHS of `:=` expects an expression. `{` basically combines expressions into one expression, see `help("{")`.